# Open external editor from python readline?

Tags: python, bash, vi, readline

I have a python command line app that uses the readline module facilitate edting user input.  My wrapper for raw_input() is

```
import readline
def rlinput(prompt, prefill=''):
    """
    Get user input with readline editing support.
    """
    readline.set_startup_hook(lambda: readline.insert_text(prefill))
    try:
        return raw_input(prompt)
    finally:
        readline.set_startup_hook()
```

I'm running under OS X and have a .inputrc that contains

```
set editing-mode vi
```

and my environment has

```
EDITOR=/usr/local/bin/mvim -f
VISUAL=/usr/local/bin/mvim -f
```

**Is it possible to get the python readline module to honor 'v' in command mode to open mvim for those cases where I need the full power of an editor for lengthy input?**

That works in bash but not in my python program.  Otherwise, editing is the same in bash and python.

FWIW, the %edit magic in **ipython** also opens mvim, so it seems like there are no obvious shell config issues.

I've looked at the doc for the readline module but I don't see anything that deals explicitly with enabling an external editor.

Comment: It's not `editing-mode` you need to set, but the `EDITOR` environment variable: `export EDITOR=vi`

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, but that had no effect in python or bash.